# Julia. Specifying tolerance for fzero (in Roots package)

Tags: julia

I can't seem to find an option for specifying convergence tolerance levels when using fzero over a given range e.g. something along the lines of

```
wageresult= fzero(fbargsolve, wageguess0, [wagemin,wagemax], ftol=1e-5,xtol=1e-5)
```

Any ideas?

When I use this in the way specified below, I get a convergence failure which I think is because the default tolerance is overly strict for my purposes:

```
wageresult= fzero(fbargsolve, wageguess0, [wagemin,wagemax])
```

The error message is "Convergence failed("More than 15 iterations before convergence")"

Comment: That 15 comes from the default for the `maxeval` argument for the subroutine that handles the case where a bracket has been found. It could be relaxed. For your problem, if you set `maxeval` to some higher number, do you find convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `fzero` with an initial guess within a bracket, the only options to control convergence are `maxeval` and `xtol`, `maxeval` controls **maximum number of iterations** and it's default value is 15, you can set it to higher values. `xtol` is **acceptable error** and it's default is `zero(float(a))` that means *machine precision* so it's already as low as possible.

an other way is to use `fzeros` function, it attempts to find all simple zeroes of `f` within an interval `[a,b]` available options for `fzeros` are `no_pts=251` **subintervals count**, `ftol=10*eps()` and `reltol=0.0`

**Roots v0.1.18**

Comment: Thanks, yes raising maxeval got me convergence.

Comment: quick follow-up: is it possible to specify another root finding method using the 'order' command while also maintaining bounds? I tried   "fzero(fbargsolve, BW0, [minw,maxw],maxeval=50,xtol=tol1,order=8)" but it didn't recognise the order keyword though it worked when the bounds in square brackets were removed.

Comment: As I remember from my old numerical computation course in university, these two approaches can't be simultaneously act in a basic zero finding method. mainly because when you choose an ordered model until the solution is on going it's not possible to guess where will the solution converge, so none of the iteration can be reject even if they are off bound. so based on my own experience, I suggest to apply multiple calls to `fzero` with different random and in-bound initial values, and with desired order, until it converge in demanded bound.